# Google create enterprise 403 error on get signup url request

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, mdm

I am trying to create new enterprise in my emm provider.
here is code

```
error_reporting(0);
$projectId = "api-7288506515928753288-19357";
$callbackUrl = url('emm/create/enterprise');
$callbackUrl = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $callbackUrl);

$authFile = storage_path('app/key/dv-505f70dd1be9.json');
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={$authFile}");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidenterprise');

// returns a Guzzle HTTP Client
$httpClient = $client->authorize();
$response = $httpClient->post("https://www.googleapis.com/androidenterprise/v1/enterprises/signupUrl?callbackUrl={$callbackUrl}");

$response = json_decode( $response->getBody()->getContents() );
// $request->session()->put('signupUrlName', $response->name);
// $request->session()->put('signupUrl', $response->url);

return json_encode( $response );
```

I got below responce

```
{
error: {
errors: [
{
domain: "androidenterprise",
reason: "forbiddenNotAnMdm",
message: "The caller is not registered as an MDM."
}
],
code: 403,
message: "The caller is not registered as an MDM."
}
}
```

I already checked on https://content-androidmanagement.googleapis.com/v1/signupUrls api.
This api is working right .

in short authentication is right with proper scope . But can t able to figure out responce.

Comment: Hey! Why do you need to use the Google Play EMM API? Why not using the Android Management API instead?

Comment: @Fred I need unenroll api. And this api is not in android management.But I found more apis in emm api.

Comment: Unenroll shouldn't be needed any more with the Android Management API, the enterprise admin (the account who signed up) can delete the enterprise by visisting play.google.com/work. What was your use case for unenrolling the enterprise?

Answer (score 0):

To use the Google Play EMM API you need to be registered in the [EMM Community](https://developers.google.com/android/work/register).

But you shouldn't need to use this API anymore, instead you should use the new [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/) that gives the same capabilities, and more.

Comment: Please check https://developers.google.com/android/management/quickstart here for delete enterprise you need to do it manually but I want this programatically

Comment: You cannot delete the enterprise programmatically, even with the Play EMM API. The enterprise is created by the admin (the account used to sign up), so it is deleted by the admin. Unenroll in the EMM API just removes the binding between the enterprise and the EMM, but doesn't delete the enterprise.